# Changing THOUSANDS with many

Tags: adjectives

I have a sentence like this:

> Of the *thousands* of expectant mothers.

I need to change the word *thousands* with *many* or *numerous*.

Could anyone help with the correct format?

Comment: You can use "of the many expectant ..."

Comment: @YosefBaskin thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 'of the many expectant mothers', or 'of the numerous expectant mothers'.